# How do I make carousel slideshow smaller?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

My Carousel goes fullscreen but I want it to be smaller, like putting a margin to the left and right, so it does not take up the whole page. Tried it with CSS but no luck so far.

```
<section id="slider">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="wildfire1.jpg" alt="waldbrband1"> </div>
      <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="wildfire2.jpg" alt="waldbrand2"> </div>
      <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="wildfire3.jpg" alt="waldbrand3"> </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a> 
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: you also have to add class="img-responsive" for Bootstrap 3 and class="img-fluid" for Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way of doing it but you could just put your code in a container like so:

```
<div class="MySlider-container">
<section id="slider">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="wildfire1.jpg" alt="waldbrband1"> </div>
      <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="wildfire2.jpg" alt="waldbrand2"> </div>
      <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="wildfire3.jpg" alt="waldbrand3"> </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators"
      role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a> 
  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

And your css code would look something like this:

```
.MySlider-container {
  margin-left: 5rem;
  margin-right: 5rem;
}
```